# make multiple header divs sticky on scroll?

Tags: header, zurb-foundation, sticky

I have 3 headers on my page. Amongst them, the top and bottom header are needs to be sticky when scrolled.The middle one gets hidden as window get scolled. I'm using Foundation 5, but, in that case sticky get applied to last header in the page.

Looking for a solution. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a jQuery snippet to attach a 'sticky' class to the headers once you've scrolled past a certain point on the page (for example when one of the headers hits the top of the viewport).

Something like this would do the trick:

```
var headerTop = $('.your-header').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerTop) {
        $('.your-header').addClass('sticky');
    }
    else {
        $('.your-header').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```